# How can I add custom fonts while converting pdf to html using pdfbox?

Tags: java, html, pdf, pdfbox

I am using pdfbox-2.0.9, I have written a code to convert pdf to PDDocument and used PDFDomTree to parse dom tree and produce an html document, but the fonts are getting messed up in an output html. I realised that there are 14 standard fonts and fonts I required are not there in standard list.

So is there any way to seed custom fonts before or along with `PDDocument.load(pdfFile)` method call, or any alternate solution to convert pdf to html using custom fonts?

```
public String convertToHtml(File pdfFile, String destinationDir) {

        if (!destinationDir.endsWith("/")) {
            destinationDir += "/";
        }

        String outfile = "";
        String fileName = pdfFile.getName();

        if (fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf"))
            fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.length() - 4);
        outfile = destinationDir + fileName + ".html";

        PDDocument document = null;
        try {
            File outputHtml = new File(outfile);
            outputHtml.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            outputHtml.createNewFile();

            document = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
            PDFDomTree parser = new PDFDomTree(PDFDomTreeConfig.createDefaultConfig());
            Writer output = new PrintWriter(outfile, "utf-8");

            parser.writeText(document, output);
            output.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error: ", e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (document != null) {
                try {
                    document.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        return outfile;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say you *"have written a code to convert pdf to html, but the fonts are getting messed up"*. So how should we help you without you not even showing your pivotal code?

Comment: Ah, so you are using the [Pdf2DOM](https://github.com/radkovo/Pdf2Dom) parser. This parser is *not* a part of PDFBox, it merely is based upon it. You might want to make the parser you use more prominent in your question.

Comment: @mkl thanks for pointing out, I have updated my question, can you please help me to find solution now?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know Pdf2DOM at all, but that's most likely where the issue is caused, so I have no idea. That's why I asked you to indicate in your question that it's about Pdf2DOM...